# Getting a null in my console while retrieving the data from mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to access the data from the database the data is stored in distance field but while retrieving it I am getting the null in my console.

Please can anyone help me?

```
connection done
null
```

I am using the following code

```
mongoose.connect(db)
.then(()=>{
    console.log('connection done')
})
.catch(err =>{
    console.log(err)
})
const query = new schema({
    distance:{
        type:String
    }
})

const per = mongoose.model('iot',query)
per.findOne({distance:2887.2021794319153})
.then(person=>{
    console.log(person)

})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Output should be entire document with its id and distance but I am getting a NULL as output

Comment: The data has already uploaded to the database using rasberrypi by using pymongo

Answer (score 0):

Computers are not very great at representing decimal numbers accurately. Any real number stored in digital format is only an approximate representation of the value that is provided. You can read more about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html. This reasoning holds true for MongoDB too.

In this scenario, the value of `distance` in DB would be an approximate representation of `2887.2021794319153`. The value that is passed in query (from JavaScript) would also be approximation of same number. Both approximations need not always be 'strictly' equal. That's why when dealing with floating point arithmetic one should to rely on 'range' instead of 'equality'. Try the following query:

```
const per = mongoose.model('iot',query);
per.findOne({
    distance: { 
        $gt: 2887.2021794319152,
        $lt: 2887.2021794319154
    }
})
.then(person=>{
    console.log(person)

})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

In this sample code, instead of looking for exact fractional value of `distance` we are looking for value between `2887.2021794319152` (original value minus one for least significant digit) and `2887.2021794319154` (original value plus one for least significant digit). You may have to widen the range a little bit depending on system / language.

Comment: But i can't able to change the distance value it is the realtime sensor value from an ultrasonic sensor using pymongo

Comment: Even if its realtime sensor value, you should be able to change your query to a range. For example, let's say the sensor value is in a variable called sensorVal, then your query could be: `{ distance: { "$gt": sensorVal - 0.000001, "$lt": sensorVal + 0.000001 } }`